# Doctrine DQL - nested subqueries in WHERE clause throw Syntax Error

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to query data from one table based on the SUMed and COALESCEd result of two associated tables. 
The query works fine when executed as native SQL, unfortunately my application is restricted to only using Doctrine's DQL on a QueryBuilder object here.

This is how I build my QueryBuilder:

```php
$resUnitQuery = $queryBuilder->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$resUnitQuery->select('COALESCE(SUM(pc.residentialUnits), 0)')
    ->from(PropertyConnection::class, 'pc')
    ->where("$rootAlias.id = pc.contract");

$comUnitQuery = $queryBuilder->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$comUnitQuery->select('COALESCE(SUM(pwa.residential_units), 0)')
    ->from(PropertyWithoutAddress::class, 'pwa')
    ->where("$rootAlias.id = pwa.contract");

$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager(Contract::class)->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id')
    ->from(Contract::class, 'o')
    ->andWhere(
        ':residentialUnits <= ' .
        sprintf(
            '((%s) + (%s))',
            $resUnitQuery->getQuery()->getDQL(),
            $comUnitQuery->getQuery()->getDQL()
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('residentialUnits', $params['rangeFrom']);
```

The generated DQL code is as follows:

```
SELECT id 
FROM App\Entity\Contract o 
WHERE :residentialUnits <= ((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pc.residentialUnits), 0) FROM App\Entity\PropertyConnection pc WHERE o.id = pc.contract) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pwa.residential_units), 0) FROM App\Entity\PropertyWithoutAddress pwa WHERE o.id = pwa.contract))
```

This results in the following error:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'`

I found an old Doctrine GitHub issue stating that double parenthetis can cause issues, which is why I skipped them in my WHERE clause and replaced

`((%s) + (%s))`

with

`(%s) + (%s)`

The surrounding parenthesis are required for native SQL to work, and it also results in an error from Doctrine:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 174: Error: Expected end of string, got '+'`

May I be running into restrictions of Doctrine's DQL here?
According to the docs, both SUM and COALESCE are supported, as well as nested queries.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Rene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, the DBAL does not support arithmetic operations on subqueries. Additional the DBAL does not support joined subqueries, `JOIN (SELECT FROM...) ON` without using a native query.

Another issue is the `WHERE` statement of your subqueries, being dependant on the root query, will cause your root query to perform a full table scan. Executing each of the subqueries per-row, unless a criteria is added to the root query (`WHERE o.id ...`).

As the subquery `SUM` values are dependant on the root query id. You can rewrite the query to use a subquery as a hidden column and a `HAVING` clause, to filter the id result set from the added column results.

```
$em = $queryBuilder->getEntityManager();
$expr = $em->getExpressionBuilder();

$qbPC = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('COALESCE(SUM(pc.residentialUnits), 0)')
    ->from(App\Entity\PropertyConnection::class, 'pc')
    ->where($expr->eq('pc.contract', "$rootAlias.id"));

$qbPWA = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('COALESCE(SUM(pwa.residential_units), 0)')
    ->from(App\Entity\PropertyWithoutAddress::class, 'pwa')
    ->where($expr->eq('pwa.contract', "$rootAlias.id"));

$qb = $this->getEntityManager(Contract::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o.id')
    ->from(App\Entity\Contract::class, 'o')
    ->addSelect('(' . $qbPC->getDQL() . ') AS HIDDEN pc_ru')
    ->addSelect('(' . $qbPWA->getDQL() . ') AS HIDDEN pwa_ru')
    ->having($expr->lte(':v', 'pc_ru + pwa_ru'))
    ->setParameter('v', $params['rangeFrom']);

dump($qb->getDQL());
```

Resulting DQL

```
SELECT 
    o.id, 
    (SELECT 
         COALESCE(SUM(pc.residentialUnits), 0) 
     FROM App\Entity\PropertyConnection pc 
     WHERE pc.contract = o.id
    ) AS HIDDEN pc_ru, 
    (SELECT 
         COALESCE(SUM(pwa.residential_units), 0) 
     FROM App\Entity\PropertyWithoutAddress pwa 
     WHERE pwa.contract = o.id
    ) AS HIDDEN pwa_ru 
FROM App\Entity\Contract o 
HAVING :v <= pc_ru + pwa_ru
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Doctrine seems to be able to parse that now, unfortunately my database doesn't know about the two hidden alias we define in the subqueries:

```SQL-Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'sclr_46'.```

sclr_46 is the variable that is generated as the alias for the first subquery.
I'm using SQLServer if that helps.

Comment: @renecatharsis Unfortunately MSSQL does not support aggregate column aliases in the `HAVING` clause like other RDBMS do, and the ORM is not (yet) built to parse complex queries. To workaround the issue, you would need to use a native query or filter the ids prior to issuing the contract query.  For information about this issue specifically see: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7593

Comment: That's a pity. I'll have to work around it then. Thanks a lot for your support. Since your reply is valid for other DBMS, I'll mark it as resolved!